# Java final reference can be reassigned

Tags: java

I have learn about the final keyword means the refernce can't be changed.
And if the keyword can't be reassigned, why can this work?

```
for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
final TextView tv = new TextView();
}
```

The `tv` reference will be assigned for new objects for 10 times.

And its referenced object can still change it's state. If we have an integer

```
final int a = 3;
a++;        // error
```

it works

```
final Object obj = new SomeThing();
obj.setAttribute()
```

And I'm wondering that the keyword `final` is to describe the 
reference or the object it refers to.

Comment: It marks the reference. And in your `for` loop, you cannot re-assign it **within the scope of its declaration**. That is, if you try to put something into `tv` after the declaration line it won't work.

Comment: @RealSkeptic That's great. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables exist in a [scope](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope), which is delimited by curly braces `{` and `}`.

Your variable `tv` is inside the scope of the `for` block. Every time the loop executes, the variable is created again. There is not a single final variable which is reassigned; instead, the variable is created every time the loop runs.

Comment: So `tv` is destoryed when exiting the scope and created again when the loop runs again

Comment: @Samin yes indeed.

Answer (score 2):

1. case - for-loop:

   The variable is only valid inside the body of the `for`-loop.

   Because of this, you can reassign it in the loop as long as you do it only one time in the body.
2. case - `.setAttribute`:

   `final` means, that you cannot change the reference of the Object(e.g. 
   `obj=...`).

   But it does not make the object immutable(like `const` in C++).

Answer (score 1):

final for objects means that the object once declared as final can't be reinitialized using new keyword. It, however, does not stop you from modifying the object properties. also once the final reference has been assigned, you can't point it to another object

In case of literals like int, it means once that literal is initialized, it's value can't be modified